# How to make wp dropdown category load with selected option on top?

Tags: categories

I have the selected option saved correctly, but when load the page, wp_dropdown_categories still load the list by its order. I prefer to load the selected item on top. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the currently selected item has some type of identifier on it (maybe class="current") you may be able to use some jquery to grab it's value, hide it, then move it to the top.

```
<div class="topdiv">
this is top div
</div>

<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li class="current">2</li>
</ul>
```

(function() {
var top = $('.current').html();
$('.current').hide();
$('.topdiv').text(top);
})();

this worked in testing

Comment: Thanks for the code! I've figured out that wp cat dropdown is not convinient. I will code the select box myself. But I will apply your code on other places that need move.